# Linux debian package manager update $PATH

Tags: path, debian-installer

I'm currently using dpkg to manage the installation of our software and would like to install to a folder under /usr/bin/ because I think it is convenient to have all software for our system in a separate sub-folder, which is immediately distinguishable from the other software in /usr/bin/.

I would like to know how to configure debian package manager to update the path to include this new subfolder, e.g. /usr/bin/mysystem/.

Could someone help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I 'm currently using dpkg to manage the installation of our software and would like to install to a folder under /usr/bin/ because I think it is convenient to have all software for our system in a separate sub-folder, which is immediately distinguishable from the other software in /usr/bin/.

**This is a bad idea, and against the conventions of the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)**. At the very least, add symbolic links inside `/usr/local/bin/` or `/usr/bin/` (see also [update-alternatives(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dpkg/update-alternatives.1.en.html))

Try to have your software either driven by some single command (like [`git` does](https://git-scm.com/doc)) or at least have a common directory `/opt/Foo/` (with e.g. `/opt/Foo/bin/` for executables, and ask your user to add `/opt/Foo/bin/` to his/her `$PATH`)

> I would like to know how to configure debian package manager to update the path to include this new subfolder, e.g. /usr/bin/mysystem/.

This is not possible and hacks depend on your user's login shell (not the same with `/bin/zsh` and `/bin/bash`). See the [chsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) command and [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) or [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (used by shells). A user can set his/her [interactive `$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) e.g. in `~/.bashrc` (if his login shell is  `/bin/bash`)  or `~/.zshrc` (if his login shell is `/bin/zsh`), etc....

Read more about [Unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and at least [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). Look into the source code of existing shells, e.g. [GNU `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [es](https://wryun.github.io/es-shell/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com/), for more. They are often [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (or at least open source). Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your own shell to understand more what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) are invoked by it.

Read some [textbook about operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Maybe take inspiration from [ssh-agent(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-agent.1.html). Sometimes, I have `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` in some of my shell scripts, such as those [using 
`startx`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/startx.htm).